# Filepicker.io: Setting cache-control headers when storing files to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, filepicker.io

I'm using filepicker.io to upload files to my S3 bucket, which works great, but how are people setting the cache-control headers once it gets there?  Apparently there is no support for configuring headers via the filepicker.io API and I'm trying to figure out what the best alternative is.

I looked at CloudFront to configure a custom TTL, but without the cache-control headers being set it didn't seem like browsers would actually cache things (there is an ominous warning about it being browser dependent).

**Origin does not add Cache-Control max-age directive**

- CloudFront caching—Objects are cached for the greater of 24 hours or
  the CloudFront Minimum TTL.
- Browser caching— Depends on the browser.

Or do I need to make additional calls from my server just to set the headers?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set cache cache-control headers while storing in S3 via filepicker.

But you can set it on browser side when filepicker file is downloaded.
Just add

```
{cache: true}
```

attribute to filepicker function.